# Change matrix environments to use parenthesis from specific font

Tags: fonts, xetex, brackets

Here is what I tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{environ,scalerel}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont{OldStandard-Regular.otf}[range={"0028,"0029},]

\let\pmatrix\relax
\let\endpmatrix\relax
\NewEnviron{pmatrix}{\scaleleftright[.8ex]{(}{\begin{matrix}\BODY\end{matrix}}{)}}


\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        \scaleleftright[2ex]{(}{a^{\dfrac{n^{k}}{2}}}{)}\\
        \begin{pmatrix}
            ajsbdjkhfbv & \mbox{ where}\\
            \alpha,\beta,\Omega & \mbox{ otherwise}
        \end{pmatrix}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

The `scalerel` package is supposed to help with using the parenthesis from said font and adjusting with the size. But I keep getting this error:

`Argument of \pmatrix has an extra }. ^^I\end{align*}`

`Paragraph ended before \pmatrix was complete. ^^I\end{align*}`

Note: there is no restriction, any solution that can handle this will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution. It avoids to take the whole body of the environment as a argument by composing the body of that environment in a box (`\l_masum_box`). That box is then used in the second mandatory argument of `\scaleleftright`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont{OldStandard-Regular.otf}[range={"0028,"0029},]

\ExplSyntaxOn
\box_new:N \l_masum_box
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{pmatrix}{}
   { 
     \hbox_set:Nw \l_masum_box 
     \c_math_toggle_token
     \begin{matrix}
   }
   { 
     \end{matrix}
     \c_math_toggle_token
     \hbox_set_end:
     \scaleleftright[.8ex]{(}{\box_use:N \l_masum_box}{)}
   }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        \scaleleftright[2ex]{(}{a^{\dfrac{n^{k}}{2}}}{)}\\
        \begin{pmatrix}
            ajsbdjkhfbv & \mbox{ where}\\
            \alpha,\beta,\Omega & \mbox{ otherwise}
        \end{pmatrix}
     \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

This code must be compiled with xelatex or lualatex (since it uses `unicode-math`).

[image: Output of the above code]